# Transform JSON data for ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm learning how to use ChartJs and I've hit a wall. I need to figure out how to transform JSON to labels and data for a bar chart.

The JSON is a products array of orders. There could be any number of products, so I need to filter through and build up a products list for the ChartJS labels. I then need to count how many times the product appears in the JSON to determine how many of those products were sold.

```
[

{
    "order_id": 1,
    "product_name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 2,
    "product_name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 3,
    "product_name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 4,
    "product_name": "monster truck"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 5,
    "product_name": "spark plug"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 6,
    "product_name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 7,
    "product_name": "can of peaches"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 8,
    "product_name": "monster truck"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 9,
    "product_name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "order_id": 10,
    "product_name": "orange"
  }

  ]
```

I am hoping to create two arrays for the products labels and product orders

```
Labels: ["apple", "orange", "monster truck", "spark plug", "can of peaches"]
Orders: [2, 4, 2, 1, 1]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try also this solution(a bit shorter):

```js
//@ts-nocheck

const products = [
  {
    order_id: 1,
    product_name: "apple",
  },
  {
    order_id: 2,
    product_name: "orange",
  },
  {
    order_id: 3,
    product_name: "orange",
  },
  {
    order_id: 4,
    product_name: "monster truck",
  },
  {
    order_id: 5,
    product_name: "spark plug",
  },
  {
    order_id: 6,
    product_name: "apple",
  },
  {
    order_id: 7,
    product_name: "can of peaches",
  },
  {
    order_id: 8,
    product_name: "monster truck",
  },
  {
    order_id: 9,
    product_name: "orange",
  },
  {
    order_id: 10,
    product_name: "orange",
  },
];

const map = {};
products.forEach(
  (product) =>
    (map[product.product_name] = (map[product.product_name] ?? 0) + 1)
);

const Labels = Object.keys(map);
const Orders = Object.values(map);
console.log({ Labels, Orders });
```

Comment: This worked - many thanks!

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little about this line please? (map[product.product_name] = (map[product.product_name] ?? 0) + 1)

Comment: Of course. First i check if `map[product.product_name]` already exist. If it exist I add it to one, - if not then using `0` instead. Since first time `map[product.product_name]` will be `undefined` I use `0 + 1`, so when first product_name is found I add 0 and 1. Check this also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator  ask if you still do not understand something.

Comment: `map` is basically mapping product_name to count of times it exist in array. So when existing product is added to map I add existing value +1

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = [

    {
        "order_id": 1,
        "product_name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 2,
        "product_name": "orange"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 3,
        "product_name": "orange"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 4,
        "product_name": "monster truck"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 5,
        "product_name": "spark plug"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 6,
        "product_name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 7,
        "product_name": "can of peaches"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 8,
        "product_name": "monster truck"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 9,
        "product_name": "orange"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 10,
        "product_name": "orange"
    }

];

const labels = [...new Set(array.map(value => value.product_name))];
const orders = labels.map(value => {
    return array.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>  {
        console.log(currentValue);
        if (currentValue.product_name === value) {
            return previousValue + 1;
        }
        else {
            return  previousValue;
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Read about these array methods here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

The Set is used to only get an array of the unique values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set

But because the Set object doesn't have these methods we transform it back to an Array using the spread operator (...)